# How to clear DOM variables and storage when a new innerHTML is loaded dynamically for a Single page application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

Im loading a Dynamic HTMLs with JS into a div in a index page.
 the index page div will be updated with another HTML file dynamically using JQuery.load function, according to the users action in the page.

The HTML also contains JS, and JS files are loading into DOM and its working perfectly as expected. but the problem is whenever a new HTML and JS is loaded, the DOM is getting updated, and its not refreshed.
the variables in previous JS files are still visible in Firefox dom stack.

i need to clear/refresh the DOM whenever a new HTML is loaded.

This application needs to be supported in IE8, so im not using angularJS. Heared angular is clearing DOM while loading new innerHTML files for Single page application.

please help me to clear DOM or suggest me any library files are available?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely to be no silver bullet for this problem. Your scripts shall probably have some custom event or callback during which they would clear/reset/refresh variables that are set to DOM elements. This event or callback then should be called every time the document is updated through the usage of innerHTML.